# Debug a faulty stereo

Tags: electrical, audio

I have a 2010 Mazda 3 with about 60K miles on it, 3rd owner.

It has a faulty speaker or speaker system. It started about 1 month after we bought it, that the speakers would begin a loud thudding, seemed to be all over the cabin rather than coming from one specific speaker. Once the problem started, it was not intermittent but right upon start up it would continue until the car was powered off each time. This thumping persisted even with the stereo powered off. I pulled the speaker fuse and it stopped.

I'm wondering how to debug and repair the issue - aside from ripping the fuse out :)

Comment: What's the frequency of the thudding? Or is that a crackling noise? Have you tried disconnecting the stereo (instead of powering it off) once the thudding appeared?